# Is the following Fortran 'do concurrent' loop valid?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran2008

I don't think that the following `do concurrent` Fortran loop is valid, as `acc` is modified in every iteration. However, gfortran is not giving me any kind of warning, and the resulting value in `acc` is correct at 55. Is it valid or not?

```
integer :: acc, i
acc = 0
do concurrent (i=1:10)
    acc = acc + i
end do
```

Comment: Note that the compiler is not *required* to vectorize or parallelize a concurrent loop; the concurrent part just guarantees to the compiler that vectorization/parallelization would be safe (which in this case is wrong). With many compilers, `do concurrent` is therefore simply replaced with a regular `do` loop; since your code gave the correct answer, your compiler probably did this.

Answer (score 4):

The loop is indeed not valid.  The compiler is not required to detect this and report the reason in this case.

In Fortran 2008 8.1.6.5 ('Restrictions on DO CONCURRENT constructs') we have as one restriction:

> A variable that is referenced in an iteration shall either be previously defined during that iteration, or shall not be defined or become undefined during any other iteration. A variable that is defined or becomes undefined by more than one iteration becomes undefined when the loop terminates.

`acc` is such a variable that becomes defined (being on the left-hand side of an intrinsic assignment statement) by more than one iteration (all of them).  The loop is thus a bad one (and at the end of the loop construct `acc` is undefined, so checking its value is also naughty).

As noted in the comments, and similarly to other invalid Fortran programs, you may still appear to get the correct answer without any complaints here. In this case, a DO CONCURRENT construct could be implemented in exactly the same way as a normal DO construct to give exactly the same answer. Only when running in parallel (say with autoparallelization or on GPUs), or with very strict compiler checks, would the data dependency result in a race condition and a wrong answer or abort.

Comment: The problems may not show up until you invoke auto-parallelization.